# Convert some array items into integers and split them up

Tags: python, arrays, split, type-conversion

Ok, I did a lot of research and really couldn't find anything that fit my situation.

I have an array that looks like

```
[['Task Name1', 'Enter Task Description1', '1', '1', '1', '1.0'], ['Task Name2', 'Enter Task Description2', '1', '3', '2', '0.16666666666666666']]
```

Basically, I want to split these 2 (and many more depending on how many tasks/subarrays there are) arrays into 2 separate arrays. I tried to do that but the thing is the "task names" above can be literally anything so to sort based on those is not a viable solution. I then want to convert each of the number values in those strings into floats and sort all of the arrays into the order of the **last** number in each sub-array. So basically, if this were my array

```
[['Task Name1', 'Enter Task Description1', '1', '1', '1', '1.0'], ['Task Name2', 'Enter Task Description2', '1', '3', '2', '0.16666666666666666'], ['Task Name3', 'Enter Task Description3', '2', '1', '2', '1.2']]
```

I would extract each of the task names and put them in order of the last integer's value/strength. If possible, I would want to kind of assign each of these numbers into a subsection under the task name. Keep in mind the task name can be anything, literally anything.

So after coming up with this, I tried different methods like "sort" but of course, they either didn't work or returned an error because I do not know how to do literally any of this [Im new to python (or at least this side of it)]. So I've turned here, as a last resort for you guys to help me fix this and get it to work. I just need to know:-

a. Convert the numbers in the array into integers and keep them inside of the same subarrays
b. Sort each of these "subarrays" in the order of the smallest to the biggest value of the last integer
c. Get all the variables of a subarray out based on the last integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what you wanted(I hope)(if you have questions - ask):

```
lst = [['Task Name1', 'Enter Task Description1', '1', '1', '1', '1.0'], ['Task Name2', 'Enter Task Description2', '1', '3', '2', '0.16666666666666666'], ['Task Name3', 'Enter Task Description3', '2', '1', '2', '1.2']]
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1], reverse=True)
for lsts in lst:
    for index, item in enumerate(lsts):
        if item.isdigit():
            lsts[index] = int(item)
        else:
            try:
                lsts[index] = float(item)
            except ValueError:
                pass

    print(lsts[0])

print(lst)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My question wasn't very clear but I really appreciate you helping me out.

Comment: Using the `lsts[integer]` method I only can print/get variables from one subarray(it stops after I exceed the limit in that array), is it possible to use this to print it from the other arrays too (or get it to start from the beginning so I can work from there).

Comment: @ShafayAsghar you can add up indexes like this: `lsts[index1][index2]` and so on

Comment: yes but if there was another array inside that array you would get first item of that subsubarray. or maybe I did not understand your question

Comment: no no, I was using lsts rather than lst, it was my bad. Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to sort the array based on the last value of each subarray:

```py
lst = [['Task Name1', 'Enter Task Description1', '1', '1', '1', '1.0'], ['Task Name2', 'Enter Task Description2', '1', '3', '2', '0.16666666666666666'], ['Task Name3', 'Enter Task Description3', '2', '1', '2', '1.2']]
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1])  # -1 accesses last item 
print(lst)
```

You can then proceed to manipulate the data types as you need